# Trocar Long por BigInteger ou BigDecimal?

Tags: java, biginteger

Estou tentando ler do teclado um numero inteiro muito grande, vi que existem os tipo BigInteger ou Bigdecimal, não sei se eles são maiores que o Long.

estava querendo ler do teclado numeros com 10 ou 14 algarismos mas o Long não esta suportando,

poderia estar usando um desses dois tipos para fazer isso? como?

```
 import java.util.Scanner; import java.math.BigDecimal;


 /**
  *
  * @author Mateus
  */
 public class Fatorial {

     /**
      * @param args the command line arguments
      */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       long a=1,num,fat,res;
         String aa;
         Scanner ler = new Scanner (System.in);


         while (a == 1){
          res=1;   

                 System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"); 
                 System.out.println("");

                     System.out.println("Digite o numero que vc queira descobrir seu fatorial:");   
         num = ler.nextLong();


         for (fat=1;fat<100000;fat++){
             res=fat*res;


             if(res==num)
                 break;
         }



         aa = String.valueOf(fat);

          if (fat == 100000){
             aa = "Não existe numero para esse resultado";
          }
             System.out.println("O numero do fatorial é: "+aa);

             System.out.println("");
             System.out.println("");


                     System.out.println("Digite 1 para calcular novamente ou 0 para sair");
                     a = ler.nextInt();




         }


     }

 }
```

A ideia do programa é fazer o inverso do fatorial, em vez de se digitar um numero e ter o resultado o fatorial, se digita o resultado do fatorial, e tem-se o numero que chegaria a esta fatorial.

PS. O programa funciona com numero de até  9 algarismos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse seu exemplo, substitua a variável `res` por uma `BigInteger`, assim:

```
BigInteger num = BigInteger.ONE;
```

E no laço for faz assim:

```
for(fat=1;fat<=100000;fat++){
    num = num.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(fat));
}
```

Preste atenção para não abusar e usar valores muito altos.

Answer (score 1):

O long suporta até o valor de -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 até +9,223,372,036,854,775,807, ou seja, o long dá conta dos 14 algarismos, suportando até 19 algarismos.

### Exemplo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long teste = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println(teste);
    System.out.println("Algarismos suportados: " + String.valueOf(teste).length());
}
```

Saída:

```
9223372036854775807
Algarismos suportados: 19
```

### Exemplo com BigInteger

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger teste = new BigInteger("9");
    BigInteger teste2 = new BigInteger("9");
    System.out.println(teste.add(teste2));
}
```

Saída:

```
18
```